# Anlaut sp-, spr- und die Wurzel *per

Tags: etymology

Vergleicht man *sprengen*, *springen*, *sprühen*, *sprechen*, *spüren* und anderes, liegt der Verdacht nahe, diese enthalten die indogermanische Wurzel [*per-~*pre](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/per-), von der auch *fahren* hergeleitet wird.

Das s- bedürfte einer Erklärung. Einerseits ist s-mobile als Konzept eher ungewiss. Andererseits würde ich naiv ein Überbleibsel von *egHs- "ex-" vermuten.

**Gibt es darauf konkrete Hinweise?**

Zur Motivation:

- *springen - auffahren*, eventuell mit *h₃reǵ- (*rect-*) als suffix.
- *sprechen - Ausführungen machen*, En. *express*.
- *Sport - Ertüchtigung* Lat. *deporto* "ausführen".
- *spüren - erfahren*, spirit, esprit, aspirieren.
- *Spur - Fährte*.

Zu *per siehe etwa Svensson [Indo-European *pr- and *pr̥h₂- ‘before, in front of’](https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/indo.2018.123.issue-1/if-2018-0006/if-2018-0006.xml?rskey=ZZJXaa&result=2&q=Per+pro) Indogermanische Forschungen, Band 123, Heft 1. Seiten 137-158.

Comment: High Level Sprach(Raketen)Wissenschaftler Frage. Mir war noch nicht mal bewusst, dass zwischen diesen Anlauten eine Beziehung besteht, dazumal die Wörter komplett unterschiedliche Bedeutungen haben.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bei etymologischen Fragen zahlt es sich aus, erst mal im Kluge [nachzuschauen](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

**Sport**: Der Kluge gibt uns unter *fahren* gleich eine Verbindung zu l. *portare*. Unter *Sport* finden wir eine Ableitung von mfrz. *desporter* (über ne. *disport* -> *sport*), letztlich von l. *portare*. Hier ist also klar eine Verbindung zu *fahren*, aber das *s-* ist gekürzt aus mfrz. *des-*.

**springen**: Aus g. **spreng-a*, wird mit gr. *spérchomai* 'Ich setze rasch in Bewegung' und "vielleicht" ai. *spṛhayati* 'sehnt sich nach, verlangt, beneidet' in Verbindung gebracht. Hier spricht also nichts gegen s mobile, die Frage ist vor allem, wie man sich den Velar am Ende des Stammes (*g*/*ch*/*h*) erklärt. (Und wenn wir das von *h₃reǵ herleiten wollen, wieso haben diese Wörter dann alle nur ein *r* und nicht zwei? (*s-pr* + *rg*) Haplologie ist natürlich immer eine Möglichkeit, aber die muss dann schon früh genug gewesen sein, um in allen Sprachen vorzukommen. Eine Ableitung von **per* ist also, soweit ich sehen kann, nicht völlig auszuschließen, und vielen Etymologen reicht das ja schon.

**sprechen**: aus wg. __sprek-a-_ 'sprechen'. "Außergermanisch könnten verglichen werden" kymr. *ffraeth* 'witzig' und alb. *shpreh* 'aussrücken, lehren' "doch stehen sich die Bedeutungen nicht ausreichend nahe" (!). Hier stellt sich noch nachdrücklicher die Frage: Woher das *k*? Und um parallell zu *express* herzuleiten, müssten wir erst mal ein von **per* abgeleitetes Wort für *drücken* annehmen. (l. *ex-premere* = (wörtlich) *aus-drücken*, und aus dem PPP l. *ex-pressus* dann ne. *express*) Wahrscheinlich kann man sich das über *fahren lassen* irgendwie rechtfertigen, aber auch hier ist die stärkste Aussage, die ich sehen kann, dass man einen Zusammenhang nicht völlig ausschließen kann.

**spüren** laut Kluge von *Spur*, also gleich dort weiter:

**Spur**: aus g. **spura-* 'Spur' von g. **spur-na* 'treten' Wieder einige ähnliche außergermanische Wörter: gr. *aspaíro* 'ich zucke, zapple', lit. *spìrti* 'nach hinten ausschlagen, trotzen, sich widersetzen', air. *seir* 'Fußknöchel, Ferse', l. *spernere* 'zurückstoßen, verschmähen, verachten'. Also wieder Verben, die irgendeine Art von Bewegung ausdrücken. Leider kenne ich mich mit Vokalentsprechungen nicht genug aus, um zu sagen, wie vielversprechend hier eine Ableitung von **per* ist, aber man muss auf jeden Fall erklären, warum hier der Vokal nicht einfach e/o/0 ist. Sonst, wie immer, ganz unmöglich ist es nicht.

Letztendlich ist aber das Problem, dass man jedes Wort irgendwie auf ein Bewegungsverb zurückführen kann, wenn man es darauf anlegt. Und jedes Bewegungsverb irgendwie auf *fahren*. Daher kann man, wenn man das Ganze mit genug Entschlossenheit betreibt, jedes Wort, das ein *sp* und ein *r* oder ein *f* und eine _r enthält, auf **per* zurückführen, und es lässt sich kaum beweisen, dass es in Wahrheit nicht so war. Eine Theorie, die nicht falsifiziert werden kann, ist aber keine wissenschaftliche Theorie, sondern nur etwas, das man glauben kann, oder eben nicht. Wenn man also glauben will, dass alle diese Wörter von **per* abstammen, kann man das ruhig. Beweisen kann man es nicht, weil nicht klar ist, unter welchen Umständen man sagen müsste, dass sie *nicht* davon abstammen.

Comment: Ich denke nicht, es wäre einfach, ein Synonym auf *fahren* für jedes beliebige Verb zu finden. Daher würde die Evidenz der Theorie allein in der Menge signifikanter Analogien liegen. Da einem *könnte sein* nur schlecht ein *kann nicht sein* gegenübergestellt werden kann, muss ich der Antwort so weit zustimmen. Daher die Frage nach greifbaren Hinweisen. Wieso ich die Frage hier gestellt habe ist mir nunmehr unklar, denn Beweise wären wohl, wie schon angedeutet, im Vergleich mit anderen Sprachen zu suchen, auch um die Behauptung zu fundieren, diese und weitere Metaphern wären quasi universell.

Comment: Diese Antwort lautet also zusammengefasst, *bs zum Beweis des Gegenteils gelte Zufall/Ungewissheit*. Die Frage lautete aber im Prinzip nur, ob ein Gedanke in die Richtung überhaupt schonmal verfolgt wurde. Den Hinweis auf Kluge et al nehm ich gerne an, da die Wiktionaries diese Quelle leider nicht immer vollständig, wenn doch oftmals hinreichend erarbeitet haben.